# Capture Android Emulator traffic using Fiddler

Tags: android-emulator

I've been trying to capture the network traffic populated from the browser and an app hosted inside the Android emulator, using Fiddler.

I've been unsuccessful even after following the workarounds of adding proxy to the emulator (Settings - More - Cellular Networks - Access Point Names - adding the system IP and port).

Comment: A question on SO requires code, exact oroblem description. this is not a forum...

Comment: [This](https://danq.me/2018/08/07/android-emulator-https-intercept/) worked for me

Answer (score 14):

You should enter this ip-address: 10.0.2.2 as a Proxy-address. You should use it cause of Android emulator haven't direct access to your local network and can't connect to local computer. 
But Android Emulator has a virtual router, so you can connect to your computer by address 10.0.2.2. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

-OR-

You can use Visual Studio Android Emulator. There's using Hyper-V virtual network adapter that can connect directly to your local network

Answer (score 13):

The point is you should switch **air-plane** mode on-off  once after fill this settings in `Cellular network setting / Access point Names` with this settings:

1. Set your system IP in -> **Proxy**
2. Set fiddler port number (8888 is default) in -> **Port**
3. Clear **Username** and **Password** field.
4. Save and exit.
5. Turn-on  ***airplane*** mode and then turn it off.

Now your data will capturing by Fiddler.

Comment: I've seen the proxy settings advice everywhere, but nowhere have I seen the airplane mode toggle!  It works perfectly now.

Comment: Toggling Airplane mode on/off is valid fix for even the Device not just emulator with a Proxy Server.

Comment: I tried to turn airplane mode on/off, but still proxying doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It just working on an old version of android.